Qt6 C++ Using Mediaplayer declared in MainWindow in another Function
Im trying to get a sound effect every time a task is added to my to-do list, however I don't want to set up the mediaplayer every time a new task is added, so I want to set it up once and then use it when it is needed. I'm not sure if this is even possible but if it is I would love to know how.
My MainWindow:
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QFile file(pathTaskFile);

    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "error", file.errorString());
    }

    ui->listWidget_1->setWordWrap(true);
    ui->listWidget_1->setStyleSheet("QListView QLineEdit{background:#FFF2D7; color:black;}");

    QTextStream in(&file);

    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem(in.readLine(), ui->listWidget_1);
        if (item->checkState()) {
            item->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
        } else {
            item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        }

        item->setForeground(QBrush(Qt::black));

        item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
        ui->listWidget_1->addItem(item);
    }

    file.close();

    // create media player for sound effect
    QMediaPlayer* player     = new QMediaPlayer;
    QAudioOutput* audioOuput = new QAudioOutput;

    player->setAudioOutput(audioOuput);
    player->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/resources/sounds/pop-6.wav"));
    audioOuput->setVolume(50);
    player->play();
}

Function to add task where iI want to add the sound effect:
void MainWindow::on_addTaskbtn_1_clicked() {
    task    = ui->toDoInput_1->text();
    int len = task.length();
    if (len != 0) {
        QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem(task);
        item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        ui->listWidget_1->addItem(item);
        item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
        ui->toDoInput_1->clear();
        ui->toDoInput_1->setFocus();
    }
}


QSoundEffect sounds like a better tool for this. But anyway, I don't see any attempt to play the sound in your callback. What if you simply connect your taskBtn signal to QMediaPlayer::play() slot? Please edit the question to show how you tried to play a sound on button click, and explain what went wrong.

The simple approach would be to create a null member, and a function to call when the sound has to be played; that function would check if a QMediaPlayer instance as been already set for that member, otherwise create and assign it, then finally play the sound file. But, as said above, doing this for a sound effect is quite pointless and inappropriate. Use QSoundEffect.
